# Bound of $\frac{\det(A')}{\det(A)}$, where $A$ is definite positive and $A'$ submatrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ symmetric and positive definite matrix, with entries $a_{ij}$. Consider the submatrix $A'=(a_{ij})_{2\leq i,j\leq n}$ obtained from deleting the first row and column from $A$. Is there a (maybe simple) bound for $\det(A')/\det(A)$ in terms of $a_{ij}$?

By Hadamard's Determinant Theorem, we know
$$ \det(A')\leq\prod_{i=1}^n a_{ii}. $$

I think the problem would be to find a lower bound for $\det(A)$.

Note also that $(A^{-1})_{11}=\det(A')/\det(A)$, so is there a simple upper bound for $(A^{-1})_{11}$ in terms of $a_{ij}$?

Comment: It seems that there is no upper bound: take $\Bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} \frac{1}{n} & 0 \\ 0 & n \end{smallmatrix} \Bigr)$.

Comment: @mechanodroid In that case, $\det(A')/\det(A)=n=a_{22}$, so this is a bound similar to Hadamard's one (in terms of $a_{ij}$, see the edit). I am not expecting a global bound working for any $A$, but a simple bound depending on $a_{ij}$.

Answer (score 2):

*(Too long for a comment.)* Unless the off-diagonal entries of $A$ are small (so that some sort of Gerschgorin disc arguments can be applied), I think it is difficult to obtain a practical upper bound. The interlacing inequality $\lambda_1\le\lambda_1'\le\lambda_2\le\lambda_2'\le\cdots\le\lambda_{n-1}\le\lambda_{n-1}'\le\lambda_n$ gives
$$
\frac{\det A'}{\det A}
=\frac1{\lambda_1}\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{\lambda_i'}{\lambda_{i+1}}\le\frac1{\lambda_1}.\tag{1}
$$
Since tie *can* occur in the above inequality, to get an upper bound of the determinantal ratio, you are essentially asking for a *lower* bound of the minimum eigenvalue of $A$. Such lower bounds do exist, but off-diagonal entries of $A$ are involved. This is inevitable because off-diagonal entries can make the matrix nearly singular, so that the diagonal entries alone cannot possibly give any lower bound for the minimum eigenvalue.

E.g. we have such a lower bound for $\lambda_1$:
$$
\lambda_1\ge\operatorname{tr} A - \frac1{\det A}\frac{n^n}{(n-1)^{n-1}}\left(\frac{\operatorname{tr} A}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\tag{2}
$$
(cf.
formula (3.2) of Merikoski and Virtanen, *Bounds for Eigenvalues Using the Trace and Determinant*, Linear Algebra and Its Applications, 264:101-108, 1997; note that the authors arrange the eigenvalues in decreasing order over there and hence they denote the minimum eigenvalue by $\lambda_n$ rather than $\lambda_1$).

Unfortunately, you still need to calculate $\det A$ in $(2)$. This makes the resulting upper bound $(1)$ much less practical because the time complexity of calculating $\det A'/\det A$ is just $O(1)$ times the time complexity for calculating $\det A$, so you don't gain much from using bounds like $(2)$.

Even worse, as the comment by user mechanodroid illustrates, the problem is inherently ill-conditioned, because by taking reciprocal of $\lambda_1$, a slight error in the estimation $\lambda_1$ would result in a large relative error in the upper bound.